# Transformation for non-normally distributed homoscedastic data?

Tags: data-transformation, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption, logarithm

I have continuous data (latency to perform a behaviour) that is heteroscedastic and also the data and the residuals are not normally dsitributed.

I've tried

- square root
- $\frac{1}{log}$ and
- log10 transformation,

but it doesn't alter either of these issues. Does anyone have any other suggested transformations?

Comment: What is your goal? Maybe it isn't a problem at all ...

Comment: I have 6 experimental groups and I want to test the differences among them. I can't use ANOVA or Kruskal Wallis without resolving either the distribution of the residuals or the homoscedasticity of the data.

Comment: First, your title says *homoskedastic* and your question says *heteroskedastic*, what is right?  Then, maybe show us a plot of your data. A boxplot by the six groups cuod be useful!

Comment: There's not nearly enough information to provide useful advice. What kind of thing is your response variable? Counts? Times? Proportions? Likert items? angles? lengths? What's your precise null and alternative?